# the test statistics and Confidence Intervals

Tags: statistics

Can some one explain how do you find t=1.68 and degree of freedom( I think 45-1= 44?) ?
I know t= (x-μ)/SE, 
[image]
!

Comment: the $t=1.68$ is dervied from the significance level $\alpha$ which should be given in the problem. The degrees of freedom is $n-1$ as a standard rule. (Although there is a reason why...) Then the $0.30$ comes from the √n-law: Your calculated standard deviation must be divided by the square root of your sample size.

Comment: so it is not derived from t= (x-μ)/SE? ty!

Comment: The formula you are referring to is to calculate the t-statistic, commonly used for hypothesis testing. We ought not to use confidence intervals for that

Comment: is there a chart for these value or a name? Cause I couldn't find it in my notes

Comment: I do not understand the down vote. This seems like a perfectly reasonable quetion.

Comment: @puppylord  Here it is: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEEQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.tamu.edu%2F~lzhou%2Fstat302%2FT-Table.pdf&ei=BTcrU6HsFaGU2gXfqIGQAw&usg=AFQjCNFnpBRf3NLOYa87sA9gLoCod_gpVQ&sig2=cg9ndGZac3HlFOb9n29aYw

Comment: thank you!, i think its in my text book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The degrees of freedom for the t distribution is defined to be n-1 (as you suspected). The value, 1.68 is usually found in a table at the back of the book. The table is usually called something like "Critical values for student's t" or something similar. You find it by looking into the table at the row corresponding to the number of degrees of freedom and at the column corresponding to your $\alpha$.